# how to make a NavLink activeClassName change background color when clicked

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to make a  nav bar when a  navlink is clicked i want  the activelink to change background-color
i have used  NavLink but it is not woeking for some reasome pls help

```
export class side extends Component {
  render() {
  
    return (
      <div className="l-navbar " id="nav-bar">
       
        <nav className="nav">
         
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active3"
            className="porpssidebar"
            exact={true}
            to="/"
          >
            <div>
              <a href="#" className="nav_logo">
                <img className="slogo" src={forur} />
                <i className="fas fa-angry"></i>{" "}
              </a>
            </div>
          </NavLink>
         
          <NavLink activeClassName="active3" exact={true} to="/orders">
            <div>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="nav_logo">
                <Orders />
                <i className="fas fa-angry"></i>{" "}
              </a>
            </div>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/customers" activeClassName="active3">
            <div>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="nav_logo">
                <Package />
                <i className="fas fa-angry"></i>{" "}
              </a>
            </div>
          </NavLink>
      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default side;
```

in app.css i have a class called active3 for changing color

```
.active3 {
  background: black;
}
```